# Which behavior of this method I should test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, sinatra

I would like to test `save` method:

```
class Note
  def initialize(password)
    @password = password
  end

  def save
    encryption = Note::Encryption.new(@password)
    encrypted   = encryption.encrypt(serialized)

    storage = Note::Storage.new

    storage.write(encrypted)
  end

  private
  def serialized
    {some_data: true}
  end
  # .....
end
```

Method just delegates work to the other classes mainly, and that's the only responsibility. My first bet to testing it is just checking:

```
  describe '#save' do
    let(:encryption){ '12345' }
    it 'calls encryption' do
      expect_any_instance_of(Note::Encryption).to receive(:encrypt)
      subject.save
    end

    it 'saves the file with data' do
      expect_any_instance_of(Note::Storage).to receive(:write)
      subject.save
    end
  end
```

I've problem with this approach as I'm little bit afraid that these tests don't test too much... Moreover test now is high coupled with the implementation not behavior. Do anyone know how to approach to this kind of methods. Worth to mention that this class would be at the top of system as wraps some resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would test a bit more, because I would like to be sure about the arguments passed to that methods:

```
class Note
  def initialize(password)
    @password = password
  end

  def save
    encrypted = Note::Encryption.new(@password).encrypt(serialized)
    Note::Storage.new.write(encrypted)
  end

private

  def serialized
    {some_data: true}
  end
end

# the test
describe '#save' do
  let(:password) { 'secret password' }
  let(:encryted) { 'encrytped string' }
  let(:storage) { double(:write => true) }
  let(:note_encryption) { double(:encrypt => encrypted) }

  subject(:note) { Note.new(password) }

  before do
    allow(Note::Encryption).to receive(:new).with(password).and_return(note_encryption)
    Note::Storage.stub(:new => storage)
  end

  it 'encrypted the password' do
    note.save
    expect(Note::Encryption).to have_received(:new).with(password)
    expect(note_encryption).to have_received(:encrypt).with(serialized) # mock serialized?
  end

  it 'stores the encryted string' do
    note.save
    expect(storage).to have_received(:write).with(encrypted)
  end
end
```

Comment: You have a typo: `.and_return(:note_encryption)` should be `.and_return(note_encryption)`, also I would add `with(password)` before that.

Comment: Cool, idea is clear to me, but what is confusing, is how code and tests are coupled together in this case. Any change with interface let's say Note::Encryption will bring changes to 2 tests, `Note::Encryption` itself and `Note`. I thought that cool test should to work if output&behavior is the same although implementation changed. Do you write code in this way usually ?

Comment: You can now remove the `have_received(:new)`, since there is no way it would have gotten `note_encryption` otherwise (and also `expect`, and not `except`...)

Comment: @LeszekAndrukanis: It depends on what is important for you. If it is the delegation, test that the method delegate the right arguments to the right method. If you are more interested into side effects and return values, you perhaps want to do integration test with the real Encryption object and just test the return value of the save method.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the method, there are a few discrete things that it is doing:

```
def save
  encryption = Note::Encryption.new(@password)
  encrypted   = encryption.encrypt(serialized) # first action

  storage = Note::Storage.new

  storage.write(encrypted) # second action
end
```

Those are the things you should test, along with validations - what happens if `@password` is an empty string?

Tests could look something like this:

```
let(:password) { 'my_pass' }
let(:note)     { Note.new(password) }
let(:result)   { note.save }

describe 'save' do 
  describe 'with a blank password' do
    let(:password) { '' }

    it 'fails' do 
      # assert_raises...
    end
  end

  it 'encrypts the password' do 
    refute_same password, result  #of course, this depends on what Storage.write returns...
  end

  it 'saves the password' do 
    # assert that the password is saved
  end

end
```

Also, if I can suggest a refactor -

```
class Note
  def initialize(password)
    @password = password
  end

  def save
    encrypted = build_encrypted_object
    storage.write(encrypted)
  end

  private
  def build_encrypted_object
    encryption.encrypt(serialized)
  end

  def serialized
    {some_data: true}
  end

  def encryption
    Note::Encryption.new(@password)
  end

  def storage
    Note::Storage.new
  end

  # .....
end
```

Comment: How it made testing this method easier ? Validations are out of the range this task as it's quiet theoretical

Comment: not necessarily easier to test, but easier to understand, more reusable and cleaner.  it's best if one method performs one action

Comment: cool, I can do it all night (https://gist.github.com/jaleszek/cb9390d2320e26ce75db) but I struggle with testing this not writing it clean.